# Why the elapsed time increases while the number of core increases?

Tags: r, parallels, elapsedtime

I am doing the multi-core computing in R. I am

Here are the code and outputs for each of the computation. Why the elapsed time increases as the number of cores increases? This is really counter-intuitive. I think it is reasonable that the elapsed time decreases as the number of cores increases. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(parallel)
detectCores()
system.time(pvec(1:1e7, sqrt, mc.cores = 1))
system.time(pvec(1:1e7, sqrt, mc.cores = 4))
system.time(pvec(1:1e7, sqrt, mc.cores = 8))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please, copy and paste the code so everybody can easily run it, instead of posting an image.

Comment: Thank you. I just added the code!

Comment: There is a fair amount of overhead when you call `pvec`. The input vector must be split in chunks and a new job for each chunk must be created. These operations take time. For  fast and vectorized operations (like `sqrt`), this approach can actually be slower. See the source code of `pvec` to have a grasp of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! @nicola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your data is divided into **N** parts. Each part of your data is calculated in **T** seconds. In a single core architecture you expect all operations will be done in **N x T** seconds. You also hope that all of the works should be done in **T** times in an **N** cores machine. However, in parallel computing, there is a communication lag, which is consumed by each single core (Initializing, passing data from main to child, calculations, passing result and finalizing). Now let the communication lag is **C** seconds and for simplicity, it is constant for all cores. So, in an **N** cores machine, calculations should be done in

**T + N x C**

seconds in which the **T** part is for calculations and **N X C** part is for total communications. If we compare it to single core machine, the inequality

**(N x T) > (T + N x C)**

should be satisfied to gain a computation time, at least, for our assumptions. If we simplify the inequality we can get

**C < (N x T - T) / N**

so, if the constant communication time is not less than the ratio **(N x T - T) / N** we have no gain to make this computation parallel.

In your example, the time needed for creation, calculation and communication is bigger than the single core computation for function **sqrt**.

Comment: Thank you so much!